# Class.forname, get result from a variable by running a method

Tags: java, android, class

I'm trying to get screen size from a android device using Class.forname.
The variables i'm trying to get is widthPixels & heightPixels, but I get the error

"***Expected receiver of type android.util.DisplayMetrics, but got java.lang.reflect.Field***"

here is my code:

```
public Object field;
    public String getInstanceValue(String classInstance, String fieldName) {
        try {
            Class Build1 = Class.forName(classInstance);
            Field strField = Build1.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            strField.setAccessible(true);
            field = strField.get(strField);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return field.toString();
    }
```

this is the class:

```
package android.util;

public class DisplayMetrics {
    public static final int DENSITY_LOW = 120;
    public static final int DENSITY_MEDIUM = 160;
    public static final int DENSITY_TV = 213;
    public static final int DENSITY_HIGH = 240;
    public static final int DENSITY_XHIGH = 320;
    public static final int DENSITY_400 = 400;
    public static final int DENSITY_XXHIGH = 480;
    public static final int DENSITY_XXXHIGH = 640;
    public static final int DENSITY_DEFAULT = 160;
    public int widthPixels;
    public int heightPixels;
    public float density;
    public int densityDpi;
    public float scaledDensity;
    public float xdpi;
    public float ydpi;

    public DisplayMetrics() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setTo(DisplayMetrics o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public void setToDefaults() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public boolean equals(DisplayMetrics other) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    public String toString() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
}
```

also the android.view.Display Class has a method getMetrics,

```
public void getMetrics(DisplayMetrics outMetrics) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }
```

Plz help :)

Comment: is "the error" a java run-time exception or a compile-time error?

Comment: This cannot work. Even when using reflection, you need an _instance_ and not a _class_ for retrieving instance variables. Please carefully read the [`Field.get(Object)` documentation(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-). Also nice to read: [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: true, it looks like you need to pass classInstance instead strField to the get method

Comment: Additionally, the variable name `classInstance` is a miserable choice. It is obviously meant to identify the _class_ and not the _instance_.

Comment: My links above were somewhat misplaced ... trying again: 1) [`Field.get(Object)` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get-java.lang.Object-). 2) [The Reflecion API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
Class Build1 = classInstance.getClass();
Field strField = Build1.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
//strField.setAccessible(true); No need as all variables are public
field = strField.get(classInstance); //use classInstance instead of strField
```

Also you will have to change method to

```
public String getInstanceValue(DisplayMetrics  classInstance, String fieldName)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. Although named "classInstance", this string variable is obviously meant to identify the class and not an instance. The method `Field.get(Object)` needs an instance of the class for which the field was retrieved. Not a string instance.

Comment: i see a lot of downvoting here, please indicate why

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have also mentioned change of method signature, Obviously String is not acceptable but actual instance of desired class.

Comment: @AniketThakur Then you can't call `Class.forName(classInstance)`. The whole question is somewhat weird. And this answer does no good. I keep my downvote, as it is still plain wrong!

Comment: Ok So get class with the instance itself `classInstance.getClass()`. Updated.